# How to rewrite the if else statements into reusable code using javascript?

Tags: javascript

i have written the code using basic if else statement using javascript. i want to rewrite it such that it doesnt use too many if else statements. below is my code,

```
const output = () => {
    if (result?.title) {
        if (isEmpty(result?.title)) {
            if (Name) {
                if (status === 'passed') {
                    return `${name} matches`;
                }
                if (status === "failed") {
                    return `${name} does not match`;
                }
            } else {
                return titleByStatus[status];
            }
        } else {
            return result.title;
        }
    } else {
        if (name) {
            if (status === "passed") { //repeated code as above
                return `${name} matches`;
            }
            if (status === "failed") {
                return `${name} does not match`;
            }
        } else {
            return titleByStatus[status];
        }
    } 
};

const title = output();
```

could someone help me rewrite this. thanks.

Comment: What is `isEmpty`?

Comment: if the title_message is present but have value " "

Comment: But... you do realize that if it's empty, it'll never get to that condition? `if (result?.title) {` checks if it's truthy.

Comment: @stackuser -- I think what vr is getting at, is that your second if will never be hit . Since it's nested under the first `if statement` that checks if it's NOT empty .. Although your **syntax** is correct ... `if (result?.title) { if (isEmpty(result?.title)) {` makes zero sense logically.

Comment: How many is "too many"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you can make the code much easier to read by using some single line if statements. After doing that it became clear that you could rearrange the if statements to reduce some nesting. Then I kept removing nesting until finally the repetition because redundant:

```js
const output = () => {
    if (result?.title && !isEmpty(result?.title)) return result.title;
    else if (!name) return titleByStatus[status];
    else if (status === "passed") return `${name} matches`;
    else if (status === "failed") return `${name} does not match`;
};
```

For other cases you need to pull the repeated code into a function.

Comment: thanks. does this cover all the above conditions mentioned in my question

Comment: @stackuser should do but its best to test.

Answer (score 1):

I think this does everything you want.

```js
const output = () => {
    if (result?.title?.trim()) return result.title;
    if (!name) return titleByStatus[status];
    return status === "passed" ? `${name} matches` : `${name} does not match`;
}
```

1. Check if the title exists and is not an empty string - return that.  The remaining logic deals with empty titles.
2. This check for `name` was in both cases, but now that we know the title is empty, we can consolidate here.
3. Now we know you have no title, but you do have a name, so return based on the status.  This assumes you only have two statuses.  You could expand with a switch statement instead:

```js
    ...
    switch (status) {
        case "passed": return `${name} matches`;
        case "failed": return `${name} does not match`;
        default: return `unknown status`;
    }
```